# custom style bullet points in Wordpress WYSIWYG editor

Tags: wordpress, html-lists, wysiwyg

Is there a Wordpress WYSIWYG editor plugin to make a button for adding specific ul li and ol li styling?

e.g. currently my ul li list-style-type is set as square in my css and my ul li are numbers. My client want to be able to add roman and alphabet bullet points in the Visual side of the Wordpress WYSIWYG editor instead of having to manually code the list-style-type (upper-roman, upper-alpha) in the HTML side of the editor?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial will let you add the **Styles** dropdown in the WordPress editor: http://alisothegeek.com/2011/05/tinymce-styles-dropdown-wordpress-visual-editor/ (edit: the *Method 2* described there)

[image: Adding Styles dropdown to the WordPress editor]

As options of this dropdown, you should let your client add 2 different classes on `ul` element, for example `alphabetical` and `roman`. In the CSS file of your theme as well as in the `editor-style.css` mentioned in the tutorial, style these 2 classes as you want (ex: `.roman { list-style-type: (...) }`)